# JQuery checking a checkbox based on name and value, multidimensional

Tags: jquery

I have a series of checkbox that I would like to check with JQuery on document load.
Let's say picture 783 categories 22 and picture 282 categories 17. What is the code to make this happen.

Thanks

```
<input name="picture[783][categories][]" type="checkbox" value=22>
<input name="picture[783][categories][]" type="checkbox" value=3> 
<input name="picture[783][categories][]" type="checkbox" value=17> 
<input name="picture[783][categories][]" type="checkbox" value=7>
<input name="picture[783][categories][]" type="checkbox" value=2>
<input name="picture[782][categories][]" type="checkbox" value=22>
<input name="picture[782][categories][]" type="checkbox" value=3> 
<input name="picture[782][categories][]" type="checkbox" value=17> 
<input name="picture[782][categories][]" type="checkbox" value=7>
<input name="picture[782][categories][]" type="checkbox" value=2>
```

Comment: You mean one by one? or 17-22?

Comment: I have posted an answer, but `-1`, as this question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After selecting the *target* element, for changing properties, `prop` method can be used.

```
$('input[name="picture[783][categories][]"]')
       .filter('[value=22]')
       .prop('checked', true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/52Yn6/

Answer (score 0):

`$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function($ind,$obj){ if ($($obj).is(':checked')) { /* ... */ }});`

Comment: My code checks if it actually IS already set to "checked". To set the state to "checked", refer to code from @undefined below.